# Cypress finds the element which is a text inside a div but times out

Tags: html, css, cypress

I am facing an issue in Cypress. The CSS locator I am using seems to be correct I can find it when searching it directly in my page. However Cypress is throwing this error

> ```
>     AssertionError
>     Timed out retrying after 30000ms: object tested must be an array, a map, an 
>     object, a set, a string, or a weakset, but object given
> ```

Here is my locator :

```js
     #verification_center_page_exposure > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2)> div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2)
```

I know that for a table or a list we need to loop through elements but this is a simple nested div I don't know why Cypress is not able to check this code :side_Bar is referring to the correct locator I have already share above.

```js
const myPage = new myPage(ele)
myPage.go()

      cy.get("#verification_center_page_exposure > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2)> div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2)")

        .should('contains', 'expected text')
```

Comment: Can you add the exact Cypress command you are running, and not the abstracted POM function? As well as the HTML you're testing against?

Comment: Yes I have modified the code.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to change the subject from the jQuery object yielded by `cy.get(...)` to the text within that element.

If I use this simple HTML

```html
<div>expected text</div>
```

and I run your test

```js
cy.get('div')
  .should('contains', 'expected text')
```

I get the same error:

> Timed out retrying after 4000ms: object tested must be an array, a map, an object, a set, a string, or a weakset, but object given

but switching to the text content, the test passes

```js
cy.get('div')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('contains', 'expected text')
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just a typo, you forgot to put some brackets on the method call, that is why that particular error occurs (but not very informative).

Do this way

```js
myPage.go()
  .side_Bar()
  .should('contains', 'expected text')
```

Comment: It's possible `side_Bar` is a getter, so it may not need parenthesis at the end. Without seeing the implementation, it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: Given the CSS selector he has chosen, there's a good chance this is the issue.

Comment: side_Bar is a getter so does not need parenthesis